# RTF Trademark character (&trade;)

Tags: entity, special-characters, rtf, character

I am trying to represent the trademark character in an RTF document. In HTML, I can use the entity `&trade;`, which generates the character ™.

This does not work in RTF. I have also tried `&#U153;` but that does not work either.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What platform are you generating it with?

Comment: I am using Windows. The technique in the accepted answer worked perfectly to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went into TextEdit on a Mac, wrote this:

```
xx:™:xx
```

and found it in the RTF as

```
xx:\'99:xx
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, that does answer it. \'99 is what I needed. 

I get the same thing when I use Microsoft Word to create an RTF document with the trademark character.

Answer (score 1):

That is dependant on

- Font used
- Platform

If the platform is Windows, there is a program called 'Character Map' hidden away in the 'Accessories', 'System', click on it to start it up and look for the trademark symbol, copy and paste it into RTF, you would want to make a note of the unicode sequence which is achieved by holding down the ALT key and entering the numeric code to do this.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about 'Character Map'.

Answer (score 0):

- {\'ae} for the Registered symbol
- {\'99} for the Trademark symbol